# Объекты некорректно отображаются в инвентаре и не передвигаются

Tags: c#, unity3d

https://youtu.be/Fn3U9B7wVas - вот проблема. Я могу двигать обьекты только в ячейки, которые находятся ниже по иерархии. Не знаю что делать.

Код на передвижение предмета :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragItemsInInventory : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.SetParent(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Попробовал задебажить. В итоге увидел, что когда я пытаюсь перенести объект на слот, который выше в иерархии (и стоит на переднем фоне), то рейкаст попадает не на слот, а на мою палочку. Но если убрать у палочки Raycast Target то я вообще не смогу её двигать

Comment: Как вы себе представляете возможным дать ответ на ваш вопрос? Вы бы хотя бы код предоставили, не говоря уже о самостоятельном дебаге и сообщении нам результатов.

Comment: Добавил код на перетягивание предмета в инвентаре.

Comment: Было бы неплохо проверить, что `eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast` - не null, да и что вообще возвращает `eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform`. Вы сами хоть пытались это отдебажить?

Comment: Попробывал задебажить. В итоге увидел, что когда я пытаюсь перенести обьект на слот, который выше в иерархии (и стоит на переднем фоне), то рейкаст попадает не на слот, а на мою палочку. Но если убрать у палочки Raycast Target то я вообще не смогу её двигать :( Сейчас попробую убирать Raycast Target у палочки в методе OnBeginDrag и опять ставить в OnEndDrag

Comment: То есть посчитали, что эта информация не так важна для вопроса? :)
Доберусь до пк - отвечу.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. 2 дня бился с проблемой, теперь работает.

Comment: Раз вы сами нашли ответ - будьте добры, оформите его как ответ, чтобы другие люди с подобной проблемы увидели ваше решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему. Мой обьект был на переднем плане и в итоге, когда я пытался перенести свой обьект в клетку, которая стоит выше по иерархии - мой Raycast падал на мою же палочку. В методе OnBeginDrag я сделал, что бы переменная Raycast Target у палочки равнялась false, а в методе OnEndDrag присваивал значение true.

Comment: Вы можете добавить на Canvas еще один рейкаст и назначить ему слои на которые он реагирует те что стоят у ваших предметов. А дальше через этот рейкаст и смотрите попали или нет, другие слои будут проигнорированы.